# How to find HTML attributes that starts with specific word using Regex in C#?

Tags: c#, regex

I have html code which jQuery adds random attributes to it like:

```
<td style='font-size: x-large;' jquery9202340423042='22423423424'>
```

Using c# Regex I want to find and remove any attribute which starts with jquery

I have the code below but it removes all attributes:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
     string before ="<td style='font-size: x-large;' jquery9202340423042='22423423424'>";

     //string after = Regex.Replace(before, regexImgSrc, "<$1>");
     //string regexImgSrc = @"<(table|tr|td)[^>]*?" + "jquery9202340423042" + @"\s*=\s*[""']?([^'"" >]+?)[ '""][^>]*?>";

    string after = Regex.Replace(before, @"(?i)<(table|tr|td)(?:\s+(?:""[^""]*""|'[^']*'|[^""'>])*)?>", "<$1>");

     Console.WriteLine(after);
}
```

Comment: You want to change `<td style='font-size: x-large;' jquery9202340423042='22423423424'>` to `<td style='font-size: x-large;'>` ?

Comment: Yes Thomas. You are right.

Comment: I dupehammered this to the idiomatic ["don't use regex to parse html"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags) question in order to prevent anyone else thinking that the right solution to handling HTML is with regex. It isn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use this:

```
Regex.Replace(before, @"(jquery\d*=[\"']\d*[\"'])", "");
```

Which will replace anything that follow the pattern `jqueryXXX='XXX'` where XXX is any number

Comment: You are the MAN!. Thank you Thomas!

Comment: @Shuaib you're welcome. By any chance, does it happen to be `jqueryXXX="XXX"` (using double quotes) ?

Comment: It is something like this:  <th id="td_10" jquery111306346705888388329="22" jquery11130011113662777489097="22">Feb </th>

Answer (score 1):

Why are you trying to do this with Regex?

***Regex is absolutely the wrong tool for the job*** (even though at a cursory glance, this might not be obvious to you).

Using Regex *might* work for specific cases, but will always [be a brittle solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags).

Use an HTML parser like [HtmlAgilityPack](https://www.nuget.org/packages/HtmlAgilityPack) and you can approach this far more sensibly. Now you can do something like this:

```
string before ="<td style='font-size: x-large;' jquery9202340423042='22423423424'>";
var doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(before);
var el = doc.DocumentNode.FirstChild;
var attrsToRemove = el.Attributes.Where(att => att.Name.StartsWith("jquery")).ToList();
attrsToRemove.ForEach(a => a.Remove());
Console.WriteLine(el.OuterHtml);
```

Comment: Thank you. I actually tired HtmlAgilityPack first but I realized the code was too long and I needed to do this for the entire HTML document and not just one line. That is why I decided to do it in Regex. But now I went back to HtmlAgilityPack and it is working well.